# Lisp data structure using vector in dotted pair

Tags: vector, data-structures, elisp

As a belated follow-up to [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31107/elpa-archives-directory-contents-the-data-structure-used), can someone enlighten me why the data structure used in the Emacs ELPA packages `archive-contents` files is a dotted pair of a name (symbol) and a vector that contains a great many things?

What is the advantage of doing it this way? It seems too intentional to just be a random stab. What precedent is this building on?

```
(1
 (ace-window .
         [(0 9 0)
          ((avy (0 2 0)))
          "Quickly switch windows." single
          ((:url . "https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window")
           (:keywords "window" "location"))])
```

... imagine `(1 ...)` having many more list members; e.g. the MELPA list of available packages is huge. So if I do `(cdr (assq 'ace-window THELIST))` I have the accompanying vector of the dotted pair starting with `ace-window`. It would almost seem that the list was designed to use the previous sexp. So yes, why have they used a vector in this situation? Is this a good idiomatic practice? I've heard Clojure encourages more use of arrays and vectors over lists. Is this more in keeping with Clojure's philosophy? So if a list is more like a tuple, i.e., with set, never-changing members, should vectors always be used instead of lists? Or is this a variation of the [mysterious tuple problem](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1186940/Lisps-Mysterious-Tuple-Problem)?

Answer (score 1):

> So if a list is more like a tuple, i.e., with set, never-changing members, should vectors always be used instead of lists?

There are benefits<sup>1</sup> to doing so, yes.  In particular, accessing an element is O(1) for vectors but O(n) for lists.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Sequences Arrays Vectors` explains:

> The “sequence” type is the union of two other Lisp types: lists and
>   arrays.  In other words, any list is a sequence, and any array is a
>   sequence.  The common property that all sequences have is that each is
>   an ordered collection of elements.
>
> An “array” is a fixed-length object with a slot for each of its
>   elements.  All the elements are accessible in constant time.  The four
>   types of arrays are strings, vectors, char-tables and bool-vectors.
>
> A list is a sequence of elements, but it is not a single primitive
>   object; it is made of cons cells, one cell per element.  Finding the Nth
>   element requires looking through N cons cells, so elements farther from
>   the beginning of the list take longer to access.  But it is possible to
>   add elements to the list, or remove elements.

---

<sup>1</sup> depending on the particular use-case, the benefits may or may not be tangible in practice.